# click event for dynamic web view in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using dynamic web view in my android application. I need to implement onclick event for web view. I tried this code, but i am not getting the click event

```
WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick()
        {
            Toast.makeText(QuestionPaper.this, "webview click is  working", 5000).show();
            wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }, "ok");
```

Comment: can you show us your javascript function?

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick reply, do i need to write click event in  javascript function?

Comment: Actually for what control/view you want to write click event to?